# multiple ethernet over USB devices

Tags: linux, usb, ethernet

we have an embedded Linux device that primarily uses the Ethernet to communicate. We also allow access via the USB port, to support this our device has a g_ether Linux gadget driver that creates a virtual ethernet port for both our device and the clients host. A DHCP server assigns the client an IP address saving them having to configure this them selves, while the device has a fix IP address. I believe this is much the same as how Android does its tethering

This all works fine until a client wants to use 2 or more devices at once. Both devices come up as distinct network interfaces on the clients machine, but both devices have the same IP address meaning you cannot target the host specifically! A smaller problem is that there is a slight possibility that both devices might assign the clients "distinct" interface the same ip address and cause a conflict there too, but I am less concerned about that as the IP address is random since the DHCP server assigns the address based on the MAC address and g_ether randomly generates this, so a retry should fix the issue (not ideal, but will do)

I would like to know if anyone else has faced a similar problem, and if so how they solved it ?

Comment: I don't know if this would work but have seen it suggested that bind()ing the **client socket** to the desired interface (ie, address given by dhcp) might confine the subsequent connection attempt to that interface.

Comment: Hmm this might work for a simple client side app, but we also use generic protocols to our device (ie SSH, HTTP), so we cannot control the software the client uses to connect to our device. Ideally a solution that does not require any client side installation would be good so it can just work out of the box.

Comment: One way to solve all this that I can think of would be to write a client side DHCP server and have the device connect to that, but supporting all the different operating systems and version for this software would be a lot of work, so I would like to avoid that and find a solution that is just device side.

Comment: What about having your boxes give out distinct subnets?  Plenty of space in 10.0.0.0/24  Not a complete solution though, as now your device can have different addresses - trivially determined from the network (ie, 10.0.0.1, 10.0.1.1, 10.0.2.1 etc) but still a complication.

Comment: I have thought of this, but the firmware on the box is the same, we would have to give out random subnets and hope we don't get a collision. All that is fine if the address range is large enough to make this a rare event, except our customers use an application that scans the network range looking for our service, having a huge random range would make this nightmarishly slow I think as it would have to scan 1000s of addresses (its 3rd party software that we cannot update either)

Comment: Your MAC addresses should be unique, so you can key off of those when choosing subnets for a lot of uniqueness.  And there's no need to scan beyond the subnet assigned by dhcp (on which your box should probably be 10.x.x.1), though yes, existing software could be a pain.